# What data format to do temporary editing with QGIS before committing it to a RDBMS?

Tags: qgis, editing, spatialite, personal-geodatabase

I am trying to create a temporary spatial data from a PostGIS database that a user can do the editing on. Currently, I have a service that returns GeoJSON from the PostGIS database. But I don't think it's possible to edit GeoJSON using QGIS. What is the reason?

Secondly, what would be the best format to do the editing then to convert it back to GeoJSON. I have shapefile and Spatialite in mind. The downside of shapefile is that I can only use one table per one shapefile. If for example I have a line and a polygon table, I would need two shapefiles for each. I am not sure what advantage Spatialite offers over shapefile? Is it possible to edit Spatialite data on QGIS? How comparable is Spatialite to Esri Personal Geodatabase?

Comment: It is general policy here as GIS  SE to ask one question per Question. "Best" questions are often closed as *opinion-based*, so please try to **edit** this question into something which can have a single answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the Offline plugin for QGIS? This syncs your PostGIS database to SpatiaLite and then syncs it back.

https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_offline_editing.html

If you need something custom, then go Spatialite; QGIS can edit it and you can setup triggers, views, querys etc that you have in your PostGIS database also. It is also built off SQLite, which is used as local databases for many mobile apps, particularly on Android etc. It is very useful in order to store many datasets of different geometry type in one file.

However it is worth noting that QGIS can load and edit almost any spatial data format, and conversion to any format is simple. So going from shapefile to GeoJSON or spatialite table to GeoJSON, is a matter of going 'Save As' in the layer properties.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I am trying to write a script with PyQGIS to do the task. I don't know the reason but QGIS is not editing GeoJSON, GML or KML. Spatialite seems the way forward.